# Determine if this function is superior or inferior limited

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This is the function

$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{9x^2+25}e^\frac{1}{x}$

I calculated both limits for minus and plus infinite and result it is 1, then I proceeded to calculate limits for 0 on left and right side and it is 0 and plus infinite. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(x)= \frac{x^2}{9x^2+25}e^{\frac{1}{x}} \to \frac{1}{9}$  as $x \to \pm  \infty.$

Since $f(x)  \ge 0$ for all $x \ne 0$ and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x  \to 0-0$, we have

$$\inf \{f(x): x \ne 0 \}=0.$$

Since $f(x) \to  \infty$ as $x  \to 0+0$, we have

$$\sup \{f(x): x \ne 0 \}= \infty.$$